# FlipView with zoom

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8, flipview

I have a problem with using `FlipView` with my pinch-zoom functionality implemented before using `FlipView`. Before I implemented `FlipView` I just loaded single `Image` and let user to change it using two buttons. It was not very user-friendly so I decided to use swiping functionality of FlipView.
I managed to implement `FlipView` and it works Fine. Here is my sample of code:

```
    private void downloadImage(int position)
    {
        MyWebClient wc;
        wc = new MyWebClient(); //I just added int actualDownloadedImagePosition field to know loading of which image has finished
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);

        String url;
        wc.actualDownloadedImagePosition = position;
        url = URL+position+".jpg";

        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url), wc);

    }
    private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
        {
            try
            {   

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(e.Result);
                Image im = new Image();
                im.Source=image;
                int pos = (((MyWebClient)sender).actualDownloadedImagePosition);
                flip.Items.Insert(pos-1, im); //Is this BTW right solution?
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

`downloadImage()` is executed at start for the first to images, the others are downloaded in future (when user swipe through them).

When I was not using FlipView I just could use this code in XAML (and of course suitable code in `.cs` file):

```
    <Image
        Name="foto"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="0,40,0,20"                  
        RenderTransformOrigin="0,0"
        Height="800"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        >
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener
                PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted"
                PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"
                DragDelta="OnDragDelta"
                DoubleTap="OnDoubleTap"/>
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform
                ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"
                TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>

    </Image>
```

But now I don't know how to make it right. I tried using `ItemTemplate` and some others solutions but I really have no idea how should it work.
Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: Did you try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442856/pictures-slideshow-with-pinch-zoom-in-wp8

Comment: Yes, I tried Windows Phone Media Viewer from nuget but it's quite hard for me to use it. Do you have any working code? Basic Lens sample from MSDN is too complicated. I just need to slide images and zoom it